# How to store JSF session in redis?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jsf, redis

I have a JSF - Primefaces application, I want to store the http session in redis with tomcat 8. How I can do this ? https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager is not maintain for tomcat 8.

What is the best solution to have one store (redis or other) for http session to put tomcat in cluster ?

I try spring session project http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/, but it fails with JSF.

Best regards

Comment: I suggest you to try out http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/ it supports redis, but replaces the container session management.

Comment: Serialize the session and store it? If you want session replication set up a cluster element and enable a delta manager.

Comment: I have already test spring-session, but it fails in my project, I have open an issue about my problem https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/29. And I don't want to use delta manager, but a solution to have a big cluster of machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use embeded tomcat with spring boot. Then you just add dependencies for redis and JoinFaces what is a library that enabled JSF with springboot.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And a very simple config

```
spring.session.store-type=REDIS
#REDIS
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

But i must warn you if you want to use SessionScoped or ViewScoped bean with injected JdbcTemplate than you will end up with an exception.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```